# Is there a way to represent complex numbers to store in Spark DF?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, complex-numbers

I have an `ndarray` of values with dtype `numpy.complex128`. When I try to create a Spark DF using these values, I get the error:

```
UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
Unsupported numpy type 15
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'complex'>
```

Has anyone run into a situation like this? How could I represent these complex numbers, keeping in mind that I will ultimately need to retrieve them down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex numbers are just pairs of floats. If you have a numpy array of shape `(n1, n2, ..., nZ)` and type `complex128`, you can [`view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) it as an array of shape `(n1, n2, ..., 2 * nZ)` and type `float64`:

```
>>> a = np.linspace(0.+1.j, 1.+0j, 12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> a.shape
(3, 4)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('complex128')

>>> b = a.view(np.float64)
>>> b.shape
(3, 8)
>>> b.dtype
np.float64
```

The real and imaginary parts occupy every other element of the array. You can verify that the data does not change from viewing as a compatible dtype:

```
>>> (b[:, ::2] == a.real).all()
True
>>> (b[:, 1::2] == a.imag).all()
True
```

The operation is very cheap: a new array object with different strides is created over the same data. When you de-serialize, you can trivially re-instate an array of shape `(n1, n2, ..., 2 * nZ)` and type `float64` into one of shape `(n1, n2, ..., nZ)` and type `complex128`:

```
>>> a2 = b.view(np.complex128)
>>> a2.shape
(3, 4)
>>> a2.dtype
dtype('complex128')
```